# Product count in archive page Title in WooCommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

How to show **in the archive page TITLE, the number of products**, in WooCommerce?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'add_products_number_to_category_title', 99, 1 );
function add_products_number_to_category_title($title) {
    if ( ! is_product_category() ) {
        return $title;
    }
    
    $products_count = get_queried_object()->count;
    
    return $title . ' (' . esc_html( $products_count ) . ')';
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! it does the job for the text page title shown on page. but I was referring to the title in the browser tab. Do you know how to achieve that?